# How clicking on an image anchor does NOT update my page history buttons?

Tags: browser, html, javascript, links

Sometimes when on a webpage I click on a link it takes me somewhere but the history for back/forward buttons in the browser aren't updated.

I understand this with AJAX however on several this doesn't seem to be the case. For example on [this page](http://randronov.blogspot.hu/2010/02/howto-list-all-my-functions-in-csharp-c.html) the first `img` is `a`nchored and when I click it the page history is still **not** updated. This way I cannot go back...

I've checked the source with the built-in web developer tools but neither the `img` nor the `a` html element doesn't seem to feature any special attribute. I've read the inline css rules for it but didn't contain anything suspicious.

I disalbed Javascript and noticed that then clicking the image *does* update the history.

How is this achieved technically in Javascript, especially the 'disabling history update' part?

**edit** I use Firefox 22 on Windows 7 64bit. I've tried *restart with addons disabled* and it still doesn't update.

Comment: You might want to mention your OS and browser. On my system (Linux and firefox) clicking on the image in the link you provided updates my history normally.

Comment: I can replicate the issue on IE9, but not in any other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely uses pushState() when the page is loaded.

[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)